# HP 6000 Pro Microtower & 2+ monitors

Tags: hp, display

I've been tasked with trying to make the 6000 Pro Microtower work with 3/4 monitors.  The machine itself has VGA and DisplayPort outputs from the motherboard.  I've installed a Radeon 4500 HD Video card, which has the ability to power 2 displays. I was thinking with the on-board outputs, I should be able to at least power an additional 1-2.  I've tried different on-board drivers, but no luck.

Has anyone tried something like this with any of the HP machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get an [Nvidia Quadro NVS](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/desktop-nvs-uk.html) card, the 420 or 450, it's a single card, works a treat and is designed for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: Well as long as someone else threw out a specific company, I'd go with this one any day over the other.

Comment: I've used earlier NVS cards in a variety of HP Workstations very successfully in the past, in fact my own current Z800 shipped with an NVS 295 which I've only recently changed to a Quadro 5000.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the 6000 specifically, but on almost every HP I've seen, when you install a discrete graphics card, the on-board disables itself and can't be used. So you have to get a video card that support 3+, or get multiple cards (be mindful to get cards that play nice with each other).

Comment: +1 This is the same with Dell machines as well.

Comment: Sigh, upset that there is no way to make the on-board play nicely with anything else!